# how to install symfony on shared web server?

Tags: php, symfony1, webserver

I have created a project(on my Localhost) in symfony(PHP Framework), and need to upload it on server(i.e the WEB Server), but i dont know how to do that, i got many methods on net, but i was not able to follow that. so please help.

Answer (score 1):

just push it in your project's `lib/vendor/symfony` dir and update your `ProjectConfiguration.class.php` like this

```
<?php

require_once dirname(__FILE__).'/../lib/vendor/symfony/lib/autoload/sfCoreAutoload.class.php';
sfCoreAutoload::register();

class ProjectConfiguration extends sfProjectConfiguration
{
  public function setup()  
  {
       [...]Normal setup plugins, etc.
  }
}
```

If you use SVN for managing your project source, using an external source to grab symfony is generaly advised, it will enlight your repository and allow easy updates.

Comment: no i am not using any SVN to maintain my code, just need to upload the code from Localhost To the Web server..

Comment: additionnaly to this it seems that you can do what richsage explains using FTP Cf. http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/22#chapter_22_sub_deploying_strategies

Answer (score 0):

Read this: [Deploy Symfony project to bluehost.com](http://peterlong.info/deploy-symfony-project-to-bluehost-com/)
This tutorial is based on the experience of the open source project "bookeet", You could refer to it for the source code detail.

Answer (score -1):

Use the `project:deploy` task that Symfony provides.  Add configuration details for your host into config/properties.ini and then you can call something like

```
./symfony project:deploy myhostconfig [--go]
```

Running without the `--go` flag will do a dry run without uploading any files.  If you're using Symfony 1.3+, add in the `-t` flag which will show you what files are due to be uploaded etc.

More info on this is in the [Symfony docs](http://www.symfony-project.org/jobeet/1_4/Doctrine/en/22) for deployment.

Comment: apparently I downvoted this, I don't remember seeing this post :O maybe it was alcohol hating on you :/

Comment: heh, I have that issue too, except it tends to hate on myself rather than on SO ;-) at least the following day anyway...!